# Case expression with no target object: should it be used?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I know you can use the case statement without a target object, like so:

```
case 
when condition1
  do_something1
when condition2
  do_something2
else
  do_something_else
end
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if condition1
  do_something1
elsif condition2
  do_something2
else
  do_something_else
end
```

Is there any reason the case expression allows being used with no target object? Are there any situations where one would want to use the case expression that way?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, there's no *no value* expression, it's the default case (as you would see in a C-like language).

Answer (score -1):

It may be used to check multiple expressions. Consider this example:

```
print "Enter first string: "
some_string = gets.chomp
print "Enter second string: "
some_string1 = gets.chomp
puts case
when some_string.match(/\d/)
  'String has numbers'
when some_string1.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)
  'String has letters'
else
  'String has no numbers or letters'
end
```

Here, you have to check two different variables. Maybe the experts have some different opinion.

Answer (score -1):

There's actually no difference, an empty `case` statement won't call `===` since there's nothing to call. Example:

```
class CaseExample

  def ===(other)
    puts "received #{other}"
    super(other)
  end

end
```

When called like this:

```
case
  when CaseExample.new()
    puts "got here"
end
```

Will print:

```
"got here"
```

While:

```
case "me"
  when CaseExample.new()
    puts "got here"
end
```

It will print:

```
"received me"
```

I'd rather go for the `if/elsif` if there isn't a case object to begin with since the intention is going to be clearer.